# PLGA - poly(lactic-co-glycolic acid) Synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Does anyone have experience with the synthesis of PLGA?  PLGA is synthesized by means of ring-opening co-polymerization of two different monomers, the cyclic dimers (1,4-dioxane-2,5-diones) of glycolic acid and lactic acid. PLGA is very expensive, due to its production costs. Can someone explain why is this synthesis process so expensive?

Comment: I assume it's simply a low-volume speciality. Have you got any more specifics about the synthesis? Also it's afaik mainly sold for medical applications, which makes the production expensive due to regulatory demands.

Comment: Most popular catalyst seems to be tin(II) octanoate.